# How can I do working push of Primefaces 6.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I need a `push` functionality but this simple code not working: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml

I need some specific library?

The next code is the mine; the same of the primefaces page.

CounterResource.java:

```
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/counter")
public class CounterResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String onMessage(String count) {
        return count;
    }
}
```

GlobalCounterView.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalCounterView implements Serializable{

    private volatile int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;

        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"

      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText id="out" value="#{globalCounterView.count}" styleClass="ui-widget display" />

            <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{globalCounterView.increment}" />
        </h:form>

        <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(data) {
                $('.display').html(data);
            }
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Please, help me.
Thank you!

Comment: 'Not working' is to broad. Did you read the PrimeFaces documentation?

Comment: Application Server? Browserß

Comment: And what did you debug?

Answer (score 4):

PrimeFaces Push was removed in 6.3 you can see in this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3385

You can read why PrimeFaces decided to remove it: https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-2-roadmap/

> PrimeFaces Push uses atmosphere framework under the hood and since JSF
>   2.3 provides a socket component, we believe it is time to retire Push. As with mobile, push will be deprecated in 6.2 and removed in 6.3.
>
> In summary, we’d like to focus and spend our time more on the core
>   components and features.

So your code must be referencing Push which explains the Class Not Found error using 6.3-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add atmospheric dependencies to the project.

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you will have to edit your web.xml file as follows.
web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

I use it this way in my project and it works fine.