# Primefaces Push socket not working

Tags: sockets, primefaces

im new to PrimeFaces and im trying to get the PrimeFaces Notify demo to work.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml

I have search for answer and found some info about it, but i still don't get it to work.
Im using PrimeFaces 6, tomcat 7 and atmosphere-runtime-2.4.8.

[This is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4niit.png)
Notify.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head><title>Notify</title></h:head>
<h:body>
<p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />

<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel for="summary" value="Summary: " /> 
    <p:inputText id="summary" value="#{notifyView.summary}" required="true" />
    <p:outputLabel for="detail" value="Detail: " /> 
    <p:inputText id="detail" value="#{notifyView.detail}" required="true" />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{notifyView.send}" />
</h:form>

<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notify" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
        facesmessage.severity = 'info';

        PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
    }
</script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

NotifyView.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.push.notify;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class NotifyView {

private final static String CHANNEL = "/notify";
private String summary;
private String detail;
public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}
public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}
public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

public void send() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(detail)));
}
}
```

NotifyResource.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.push.notify;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/notify")
public class NotifyResource {

@OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    return message;
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>PrimeFacesDemoNotify</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation about PrimeFaces push. Might be some relevant information in there

Comment: Does this help (sames as in the PF docs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194581/how-can-i-do-working-push-of-primefaces-6-0

Comment: Do you have to use Maven for primeFaces push to work?

Comment: No.............

Comment: (sorry for al the dots but otherwise I would not get to the 15 required characters)

Comment: So the example you gave me aren't they using maven (pom.xml). All i have is web.xml or were do I put the <dependency> code?

Comment: You don't put the `<dependency>` code anywhere, you need to use the corresponding jar files in the way you use/configure/load/... external jar files.

Comment: Ok so my problem is wrong jar files?

Comment: I have no idea... That is your side... It is a guide to what to do (as is the documentation)... What versions you require is dependent on what versions of other libraries you have. If you have PF 6.0, you can see in the PF docs what other versions you need, but ALSO what you should configure additionally

Comment: Note that this will be deprecated soon. https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-2-roadmap/ If you are using JSF2.3 use the native socket, or try Omnifaces socket instead.